# C++ map, use const reference as value type, what is the problem here?

Tags: c++, reference, stdmap

Today I saw my boss's code which uses a const reference as a `map`'s value type.

Here's the code:

```
class ConfigManager{
    public:
        map<PB::Point, const PB::WorldPoint&, compare_point> world_point;
    //the rest are omitted
};
```

(`PB` is Google Protobuf, we are using the Protobuf library. I don't know much about it or if it's relevant to the question. )

What this class does is that it reads some config files and put it into some `map`s for searhing.

---

At first I was surprised because I haven't seen a `map` with a reference as its value, which is e.g. `map<int, classA&> aMap`.

So then I searched on SO and these 2 questions tell me that I can't do that.

[C++: Is it possible to use a reference as the value in a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239253/c-is-it-possible-to-use-a-reference-as-the-value-in-a-map)

[STL map containing references does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934021/stl-map-containing-references-does-not-compile)

Then I tried this code, indeed it doesn't compile:

#### Code Example1

```
struct A {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
};

map<int, A&> myMap;

int main() {
    A a;
    myMap.insert(make_pair(1, a));
}
```

But if I change `map<int, A&> myMap;` to `map<int, const A&> myMap;`, it compiles.

Yet another problem occured. With `map<int, const A&> myMap;`, I can't use `[]` to get the pair, but I can use `map.find()`.

(My boss told me to use `map.find()` after I told him using`[]` can't compile).

#### Code Example2

```
struct A {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
};

map<int, const A&> myMap;

int main() {
    A a;
    myMap.insert(make_pair(1, a));

    //can't compile
    cout << myMap[1].x << " " << myMap[1].y << endl; 
    
    //can work
    //auto it = myMap.find(1);
    //cout << it->second.x << " " << it->second.y << endl;
}
```

So till here I was thinking my boss was correct. His code was correct.

---

The last story is that I showed the code to some online friends. And they noticed a problem.

#### Code Example3

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    ~A(){
        cout << "~A():" << x << endl;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
};

map<string, const A&> myMap;

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << a.x << " " << a.y << endl;
    myMap.insert(make_pair("love", a));
    a.x = 999;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    auto s = myMap.find("love");
    cout << s->second.x << " " << s->second.y << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
3 4
~A():3
hello
0 0
~A():999
```

If I understand the output correctly(correct me if I get it wrong), it indicates that:

1. `make_pair("love", a)` creates an object `pair<"love", temproray copy of a>`. And the pair gets `inserted` into `myMap`.
2. Somehow, I don't know how it happens, the `temporary copy of a` gets destructed immediately. To me, it means the memory of the `temporary copy of a` is now not owned by anyone and it is now a free space of memory that can be filled with any values, if I understand correctly.

---

So now I am getting confused again.

My questions are:

1. What happens to the **Code Example3**? Is my understanding correct? Why does `temporary copy of a` get destructed right after the statement? Isn't using a const reference can extend a temporary's lifetime? I mean, I think the it should not get destructed till `main` finishes.
2. Is my boss's code incorrect and very dangerous?

Comment: Sorry if the question is too long. I've tried my best to make it short.

Comment: [This example](https://godbolt.org/z/jfn4z1) leads me to believe that your boss' code doesn't work as intended. The map's referenced object doesn't appear to be the same as the original.

Comment: The bottom line should be that, even if it *did* work as intended, the fact that it results in this level of research shows that it should be avoided anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does temporary copy of a get destructed right after the statement?

Because (in most cases) that's how temporaries work. The live until the end of the statement in which they are created. The extension to a temporaries lifetime doesn't apply in this case, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary). The TLDR version is

> In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by
> "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to
> which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.

> can I use const reference as a map's value type?

Yes as long as you realise that adding a const reference to a map has no effect on the lifetime of the object being referred to. Your bosses code is also incorrect because the temporary returned by `make_pair` is destroyed at the end of the statement.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, didn't look at the code long enough

Comment: This would benefit from mentioning `std::ref`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica What can `std::ref` do in here?

Comment: @Rick - It can be used to create a pair that holds a reference wrapper to `a`, instead of a copy. Thus initializing the item in the map with a reference to `a` (instead of dangling).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. Which rule of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary, applies in this case so that the temporary object's lifetime doesn't get extended? It would be much appreciated if your answer can be longer.

Comment: To me, `make_pair("love", a)` returns a `pair<"love", copy of a>` and `copy of a` is assigned to `const A&`, there's only 1 reference here.

Comment: @Rick It is hard to illustrate without going into speculation of `std::map` implementation details. But the in short the properties of references extending the life time of temporaries does not propagate. None of the cases that allow lifetime extension covers that case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux FYI, the link given by John is about the **exception cases**. *Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference, **with the following exceptions**: ......*, so which **exceptions** exactly covers this case?

Comment: @Rick Edit :  Never mind, its this exception : "a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call:"

Answer (score 1):

You may use `std:: unique_ptr<A>` instead. Then `emplace` instead of `insert`:

```
using value_t=std:: unique_ptr<A>;
std::map<int, value_t> myMap;
myMap.emplace(1,new A);
myMap[1]=new A{5,6};
myMap[1]->x=7;
```

more on `std:: unique_ptr<A>`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: The goal seems to be to have a map that refers to elements that exist outside the map. I'm not sure that this answer is an equivalent alternative.

Comment: Since C++14 there is `std::make_unique<T>` to replace `new T` when initializing `std::unique_ptr`s. In typical modern C++ the only use case for `new` is now placement.

Comment: In c++20 there are enhancements to deductions for operator new. If the goal was reference ti existing objects, temporaries would not be used. Raw pointer is best for observer-only solutions.

Comment: Well, thank you for helping. But I am not looking for an alternative. I more want to know why.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to the Code Example3? Is my understanding correct?

Your explanation is close. The `std::pair` that is returned by `std::make_pair` is the temporary object. The temporary `std::pair` contains the copy of `a`. At the end of the expression the pair is destroyed, which also destroys its elements including the copy of `a`.

> Why does temporary copy of a get destructed right after the statement? Isn't using a const reference can extend a temporary's lifetime? I mean, I think the it should not get destructed till main finishes.

The temporary here is the result of `std::make_pair` which is being used as an argument to the member function `insert`. The relevant rules that apply here are :

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a subobject thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference, with the following exceptions:
>
> - [...]
> - a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call [...]
> - [...]

[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)

The full expression containing the function call is the expression `myMap.insert(make_pair(1, a));` This means that the lifetime of the result of `std::make_pair` ends after the function return, including the `A` it contains. The new `std::map` element will refer to the `A` in the temporary `std::pair` which will become dangling once `insert` returns.

> Is my boss's code incorrect and very dangerous?

Yes, `myMap` contains a dangling references.

Comment: I would like to point out that it's `std::pair<const K, V>`, and `V` happens to be a reference type, but `value_type` of the `map` itself, is not one. Anyway, I get the idea.

Comment: @Rick The pair I refer to when I say `std::pair` in my answer is the result of `std::make_pair`, `std::pair<int, A>` or `std::pair<const char *, A>` (depending on the example). You may be looking at `std::map<int, const A &>::value_type` which is indeed `std::pair<const int, const A &>` (or `std::pair<const std::string, const A &>`, depending again) but that has no bearing on `std::make_pair` which only looks at its arguments.

Comment: But you have to specifiy the `map` is like  `std::map<int, const A &>::value_type` form. Otherwise it doesn't match my case. Corresponding to the excpetion rule we have agreed, it's *a temporary bound ( `A` of `std::pair<int, A>` returned by `std::make_pair`) to a reference parameter (`const A&` of `std::map<int, const A &>::value_type`) in a function call (`std::map.insert()`) exists until the end of the full expression (`myMap.insert(make_pair("love", a));`) containing that function call*

Comment: Anyway, I think we both get the idea. I just think  your answer need some modification to better match my case. :P

Comment: @Rick Its not clear to me which part exactly would need improvement. I would appreciate it if you could indicate it up for me.

Comment: Check this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50753330#50753330 maybe? I don't think your answer has something wrong.