# Why map::clear doesn't call to the destructor ?

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, destructor

I run to following program , note that the `value` of the `map` is a ref `(ClassA&)` -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std  ; 

class ClassA {
    public :
         ClassA () {    cout<<"Hay ! "<<endl ; }    
        ~ClassA () {    cout<<"Bye ! "<<endl ; }
} ; 

int main () { 
    map< string,ClassA& > myMap ; 
    ClassA a   ; 
    myMap.insert( pair<string,ClassA&>("A",a) ) ; 
    myMap.clear() ; 




}
```

And get output   -

```
Hay ! 
Bye !
```

Seems like the `myMap.clear()` didn't affected cause there is no one more calling to  `ClassA` destructor     , can you explain me why ?

Comment: That shouldn't compile, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Nick I tested on VS2012 and GCC4.3.4 both worked. http://ideone.com/OW3gd9

Comment: @Nick I have g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Destructor is not called when a reference is deleted. Speaking of which.. I thought [maps with references would be illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934021/stl-map-containing-references-does-not-compile)