# Lifetime of references in STD collections

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std

How long is a reference to an element returned by an STD collection, such as a map, valid?

For example, in this code:

```
struct Employee{
   int salary;
   string name; // the key
     };

map<string,Employee> allemployees;
...
Employee & Joe = allemployees["Joe Smith"];
Joe.salary=150; // change "Joe Smith"'s salary
assert(allemployees["Joe Smith"].salary==150); //always true
 ....
allemployees["Mark Jones"]= Employee();
... // No "Joe Smith" operations in the dots
 Joe.salary=200;
 assert (allemployees["Joe Smith"].salary==200); //true or not?
```

}

In other words, I get a value reference back from a map. But then I do various other insertions, deletions and so on the underlying map. Is the original value reference still good? What about for other collections?

And also, how do I know that? I looked in Stroustrup but did not see anything.

Coming from a C background I am confused by references and collections and their interaction. Should I ever consider maps whose values are references themselves? What would that even mean?

So a more general question: where do I find normative answers to this question and similar kinds of questions?

[This is the revised version of a deleted question]

Comment: STD is a confusing acronym when capitalized `;-)`

Comment: @rubenvb - yeah... *"A lifetime of memories in STD collections"*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::map` references are invalidated by the same actions that would invalidate an iterator - that's well documented in the Standard and places like cppreference.com.

Summarily for `std::map`, the references are valid as long as you don't `clear` the `map`, or `erase` the specific referenced element; inserting or erasing other elements is fine.  For example, [cpprefererence map::insert documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) says "No iterators or references are invalidated.".

You'll find there are statements about other containers and their operations....
(jrok pointed out in comments that push to `deque` is an example of an operation where references remain valid but iterators are invalidated).

Comment: OK thanks. What about the semantics of using a map whose value type is a reference, e.g. map<string><Employee &> . Am I guaranteed that, for instance, nothing the map does will affect the underlying Employee it points to?

Comment: @kdog: you can't have "a map whose value type is a reference"... not allowed.  See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934021/stl-map-containing-references-does-not-compile)

Comment: @TonyD I'm curious, where in the standard does it say this?

Comment: The C++11 specification clearly states (§23.2.1[container.requirements.general]/1):Containers are objects that store other objects.

Comment: There are cases where iterators are invalidated but references are not, such as pushing to `deque`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the great answer and the pointer (or reference) to other sources of information as well.